# DQL Error with doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have this simple controller:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->doctrine->em))
        {
            $em = $this->doctrine->em;

            $categorias = $em->getRepository('Entities\Categoria')->findBy([], ['categoria' => 'ASC']); (*)
            $data['categorias'] = $categorias;

            $dql = "SELECT r FROM Entities\Receita r"; 
            $query = $em->createQuery($dql); 
            $query->setMaxResults(4);
            $receitas = $query->getResult(); (**)

            $data2['chamadas'] = $receitas;

            //Defino aqui o indice do menu que ficará ativo
            $this->session->set_userdata('menu_active', 0);

            $this->load->view('html_header'); 
            $this->load->view('menu_categorias', $data);
            $this->load->view('conteudo', $data2);
            $this->load->view('html_footer');

        }
    }
}
```

In line (*), it is working fine. But in line (**), I am getting the error below.

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'r0_.slug_categoria' in 'field list'' in
>   C:\wamp\www\ControleReceitas_DoctrineORM\application\libraries\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   on line 71
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'r0_.slug_categoria' in 'field list' in
>   C:\wamp\www\ControleReceitas_DoctrineORM\application\libraries\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php
>   on line 104

It´s a simple query. I wanna get 4 records from the above query, but I am getting this error. I really don´t know what is wrong. It is warning about r0_.slug_categoria field, but this field is in the other table.

My intention is to get 4 random different records in every page load. I know that my query here do not that. But I can´t do this simple one works... So, first of all, I need to understand what is going wrong to be able to go forward...

Below, are my tables structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorias` (
  `id_categoria` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `slug_categoria` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `receitas` (
  `id_receita` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `receita` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug_receita` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `texto` text NOT NULL,
  `categoria` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adicionada_quando` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_receita`),
  KEY `FK_receita_categoria` (`categoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.... the error was fired because I made a mistake inside my entity and mapping files.

Below, is my mapping file:

```
Entities\Receita:
  type: entity
  table: receitas
  fields:
    idReceita:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
      column: id_receita
    receita:
      type: string
      length: 45
      nullable: false
    slugReceita:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: false
      column: slug_receita (*)
    texto:
      type: text
      nullable: false
    foto:
      type: string
      length: 45
      nullable: true
    adicionadaQuando:
      type: datetimetz
      columnDefinition: TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      nullable: false
      column: adicionada_quando
  manyToOne:
      categoria:
        targetEntity: Categoria
        joinColumn:
          name: categoria
          referencedColumnName: id_categoria
```

The error was in line (*), where it was slug_categoria, and the correct is slug_receita.

The second error, was found at my entity:

```
class Receita
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_receita", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idReceita;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="receita", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $receita;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug_receita", type="string", length=255, nullable=false) (*)
     */
    private $slugReceita;
```

In the line (*), it was name="slug_categoria", and the correct is name="slug_receita".

I made a mapping mistake, and the doctrine entity generator copies the mapping error to the entity.

By the way... I really know now, that I need to have more attention when doing "copy and paste" !!! :)

Best regards.
Marcelo.